# Console tree view C#

Tags: c#

everyone, this is my first time posting! :D

I have a question regarding creating some sort of a tree view in a console app in C#.
I have a text file that is filled with a number of rows, that have their IDs, texts and ParentIDs.

My assignment is to order every row, so the one with the ParentID == 0 is the first, and then the rest will follow, BUT I have to use a recursive method for the order.

So far I have managed to parse the text file, place it into a class and place the classes in a list, but I have not been successful with the recursive part. Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\text.txt");
            List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] col = line.Split(",");
                objects.Add(new Object(int.Parse(col[0]), col[1], int.Parse(col[2])));
            }
            Recursive(objects, objects.Count-1);

            foreach (var obj in objects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", obj.ID, obj.name, obj.ParentID);
            }

        }
        public static object Recursive(List<Object> objects, int a)
        {

            if (objects[a].ParentID == 0)
            {
                return objects[a];
            }
            else
            {
               return Recursive(objects, a-1);

            }
            
        }
    }

    public class Object
    {

        public int ID;
        public string name;
        public int ParentID;

        public Object(int ID, string name, int ParentID)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
            this.ParentID = ParentID;
        }
    }
```

If anybody has any idea how to solve this, I would really appreciate it. I understand the concept of the recursive function, but I just can't seem to get around the logic of this particular assignment.

Here is a sample of the text file:

```
1,text,0
2,text,1
3,text,2
4,text,5
5,text,1
6,text,4
```

Comment: Post sample of data.

Comment: Posted, thank you for taking the time and looking at my problem! :D

Comment: I'm not sure if this is over complicating it or not but is it possible in the assignment to use some kind of recursive sort? i.e Merge Sort. Currently it looks like your code just searches for the object with parent ID 0 and returns it

Comment: Are your IDs GUARANTEED to start with 0 (zero) and always be consecutive integers after they are sorted?  If so, then we can modify what you've got so it'll work, but I'm wondering if you're supposed to be implementing an recursive sort algorithm instead as Jack Walton suggests.  Can you post the actual requirements for the assignment?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes, the ParentID 0 is supposed to be root, and the rest should follow in the order of their ParentID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would have done it:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) {
    // obviously, you're using a text file, but this part is inconsequential
    string[] lines = "1,a,0|2,b,1|3,c,2|4,d,5|5,e,1|6,f,4".Split("|");

    List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
    foreach(String line in lines) {
        string[] col = line.Split(",");
        objects.Add(new Object(int.Parse(col[0]), col[1], int.Parse(col[2])));
    }

    Recursive(objects, 0, 0);
}

public static void Recursive(List<Object> nodes, int parent, int level) {
    String tabs = new String('\t', level);
    foreach(Object node in nodes) {
        if (node.ParentID == parent) {
            Console.WriteLine(tabs + node.name);
            Recursive(nodes, node.ID, level+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the [complete example on Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/kvmtssse-idlemind).

By the way, we've all assumed you are looking for a [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) when you said they are supposed to be output "in order".

Answer (score 1):

Currently your program is using recursion like a while loop to find the the object with `ParentID == 0`.

```
while(objects[a].ParentID != 0){
    a-1;
}
return objects[a]
```

While you could use this kind of logic to implement a kind of bubble sort which made use of recursions instead of loops (I'm not sure why anyone would do this) a far better solution would to be use a recursive sort like MergeSort to put the list of objects in order on `ParentID`.

You can easily learn how to use MergeSort or a number of other recursive sorts by googling. Here's a link to a decent explanation of merge sort containing a python implementation that you should be able to adapt to your needs.

[Merge Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/)

If you are not familiar with sorts then you can either google sorting algorithms, or again here's a decent link.

[Sorting Algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/)

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(FILENAME);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] col = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                objects.Add(new Object(int.Parse(col[0]), col[1], int.Parse(col[2])));
            }
            int root = 0;
            int level = 0;
            Recursive(root, level);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static void Recursive(int parent, int level)
        {
            List<Object> nodes = objects.Where(x => x.ParentID == parent).ToList();

            if (nodes.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Object node in nodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}ID : '{1}', Name : '{2}'", new string(' ', 5 * level), node.ID, node.name);
                    Recursive(node.ID, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Object
    {

        public int ID;
        public string name;
        public int ParentID;

        public Object(int ID, string name, int ParentID)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
            this.ParentID = ParentID;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is form project with similar code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication68
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, Text, null});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, Text, 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3, Text, 1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4, Text, 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {5, Text, 4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {6, Text, 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {7, Text, 3});

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                objects.Add(new Object(row.Field<int>(0), row.Field<string>(1), row.Field<int?>(2)));
            }
            int? root = null;
            int level = 0;
            TreeNode node = null;
            Recursive(node, root, level);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        public void Recursive(TreeNode parentNode, int? parent, int level)
        {
            List<Object> nodes = objects.Where(x => x.ParentID == parent).ToList();

            if (nodes.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Object node in nodes)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}ID : '{1}', Name : '{2}'", new string(' ', 5 * level), node.ID, node.name);
                    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(message);
                    if(parentNode == null)
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parentNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                    }
                    Recursive(newNode, node.ID, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Object
    {

        public int ID;
        public string name;
        public int? ParentID;

        public Object(int ID, string name, int? ParentID)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
            this.ParentID = ParentID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the nature of this "assignment".  This part, `List<Object> nodes = objects.Where(x => x.ParentID == parent).ToList();`, feels like serious "cheating"...lol.

Comment: Some people like using a period : new string('.', 5 * level)    I've written this code hundreds of times since my first college course in Fortran/Pascal using punch cards

Comment: I would just use the tab character `new String('\t', level)`?